# How do I include a port into FreeBSD distro?

Tags: compiling, freebsd

I want to build my own FreeBSD installation media (an .iso file to burn on a DVD) with selected ports. What I mean is: I use a DVD to install new system, and after installing it I can (for example) use git and gcc49. Is that possible? I know it's possible while compiling source code for ARM's (like Raspi or Beaglebone), but is that possible for i386/amd64 version? Googling gave me nothing and so do posting on official FreeBSD forum. Thank you in advance for your answer. Greethings

Comment: Read [this post](http://daemonforums.org/showthread.php?t=2026)

Comment: thank you for a quick response, eyoung. Unfortunately, m0n0wall's dev handbook is a bit outdated (last update was ten years ago), and FreeSBIE boots from CD. Is there anything else?

Comment: Can you not install freesbie from a FreeBSD install port?  See the [Official Website](http://www.freesbie.org/) and install the [toolkit](http://www.freshports.org/sysutils/freesbie/).  I apologize for not being clear, but I believe the toolkit can be used to "roll your own ISO", which is what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was about to answer this question with a link to the [release man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=release&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) and go into great detail about how to build packages and include them in releases etc.

But then I realized that your question is mixing up which packages are installed after the install. Packages are no longer included in the ISO, you can install the packages by installing them from the network post install by running `pkg install packagename`.

Comment: so you want to say that pre-install programs in my release is not possible? okay, then :( So another idea: you say that I can build packages and include them in my release. Do I have to build ALL packages, or can I remove those I will not use (in example games, arabic or japanese packages etc.)? If that's possible, how do I do this? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: What I'm saying is the installer no longer installs packages of things from ports. You can install them after the OS is installed. The packages the project provides will probably work for you, but If you want to build your own packages, you can. You'll just need to setup poudriere to build and a pkg repo to install. Setting all that up is more than I can explain in the space provided in comments here. See https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/pkgng-intro.html and https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/ports-poudriere.html